# Zend forms redirecting

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am writing a code in zend to capture data from a users input and and save it in the database. I am using zend forms. The information to capture is too much, so I want to create another form to fill in the other data...how can i redirect from one form to another after filling the first form?

Here is my code for Forms, Indexcontroller and models

IndexController.php

```
   <?php

    class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
     {

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
        $this->view->organization_details= $organization_details->fetchAll();
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_OrganizationDetails();

        $form->submit->setLabel('Next');
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                

                $Organization_Name = $form->getValue('Organization_Name');
                $Organization_Trading_Name =  $form->getValue('Organization_Trading_Name');
                $Region = $form->getValue('Region');
                $City = $form->getValue('City');
                $Physical_Address = $form->getValue('Physical_Address');
                $Physical_code = $form->getValue('Physical_code');
                $Postal_Address = $form->getValue('Postal_Address');
                $Postal_code = $form->getValue('Postal_code');
                $Telephone_Number = $form->getValue('Telephone_Number');
                $Fax_Number = $form->getValue('Fax_Number');
                $Cellular_Number = $form->getValue('Cellular_Number');
                $Organization_Email = $form->getValue('Organization_Email');
                $Organization_Website = $form->getValue('Organization_Website');                                

                $organization_details = new  Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $organization_details->addOrganizationDetails($Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website);

                $this->_helper->redirector('add');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
}
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_OrganizationDetails();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Update'); //can set it here also in forms
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $id = (int)$form->getValue('id');
                $Organization_Name = $form->getValue('Organization_Name');
                $Organization_Trading_Name = $form->getValue('Organization_Trading_Name');
                $Region = $form->getValue('Region');
                $City = $form->getValue('City');
                $Physical_Address = $form->getValue('Physical_Address');
                $Physical_code = $form->getValue('Physical_code');
                $Postal_Address = $form->getValue('Postal_Address');
                $Postal_code = $form->getValue('Postal_code');
                $Telephone_Number = $form->getValue('Telephone_Number');
                $Fax_Number = $form->getValue('Fax_Number');
                $Cellular_Number = $form->getValue('Cellular_Number');
                $Organization_Email = $form->getValue('Organization_Email');
                $Organization_Website = $form->getValue('Organization_Website');
                $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $organization_details->updateOrganizationDetails($id, $Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website);

                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        } else {
            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            if ($id > 0) {
                $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $form->populate($organization_details->getOrganizationDetails($id));
            }
        }
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');
            if ($del == 'Yes') {
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
                $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
                $organization_details->deleteOrganizationDetails($id);
            }
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        } else {
            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            $organization_details = new Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails();
            $this->view->organization_details = $organization_details->getOrganizationDetails($id);
        }
    }


}

OrganizationDetails.php //model

<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_OrganizationDetails extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'organization_details';

    public function getOrganizationDetails($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
        if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row->toArray();
    }

    public function addOrganizationDetails($Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website)
    {
        $data = array(
            'Organization_Name'=> $Organization_Name,
            'Organization_Trading_Name'=> $Organization_Trading_Name,
            'Region'=> $Region,
            'City'=> $City,
            'Physical_Address'=> $Physical_Address,
            'Physical_code'=> $Physical_code,
            'Postal_Address'=> $Postal_Address,
            'Postal_code'=> $Postal_code,
            'Telephone_Number'=> $Telephone_Number,
            'Fax_Number'=> $Fax_Number,
            'Cellular_Number'=> $Cellular_Number,
            'Organization_Email'=> $Organization_Email,
            'Organization_Website'=> $Organization_Website,
        );
        $this->insert($data);
    }

    public function updateOrganizationDetails($id, $Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website)
    {
        $data = array(
            'Organization_Name'=> $Organization_Name,
            'Organization_Trading_Name'=> $Organization_Trading_Name,
            'Region'=> $Region,
            'City'=> $City,
            'Physical_Address'=> $Physical_Address,
            'Physical_code'=> $Physical_code,
            'Postal_Address'=> $Postal_Address,
            'Postal_code'=> $Postal_code,
            'Telephone_Number'=> $Telephone_Number,
            'Fax_Number'=> $Fax_Number,
            'Cellular_Number'=> $Cellular_Number,
            'Organization_Email'=> $Organization_Email,
            'Organization_Website'=> $Organization_Website,
        );
        $this->update($data, 'id = '. (int)$id);
    }

    public function deleteOrganizationDetails($id)
    {
        $this->delete('id =' . (int)$id);
    }


}

OrganizationDetails.php //forms

<?php
class Application_Form_OrganizationDetails extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('organization_details');
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');

        $Organization_Name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Name');
        $Organization_Name->setLabel('Organization Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Organization_Trading_Name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Trading_Name');
        $Organization_Trading_Name->setLabel('Organization Trading Name')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Region= new Zend_Form_Element_Select('Region');
        $Region->setAttribs(array('style' => 'width: 150px;'));  
        $Region ->setLabel('Region')
                ->addMultiOptions(array(
                            '--Select One--'=>'--Select One--',
                            'City of Johannesburg'=>'City of Johannesburg',
                            'City of Tswane'=>'City of Tswane',
                            'Ekhurhuleni Metropolitian Municipality'=>'Ekhurhuleni Metropolitian Municipality',
                            'West Rand District Municipality'=>'West Rand District Municipality',
                            'Sedibeng District Municipality '=>'Sedibeng District Municipality',

                        ));


        $City = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('City');
        $City->setAttribs(array('style' => 'width: 144px;'));  
        $City ->setLabel('City')
            ->addMultiOptions(array(
                            'Pretoria'=>'Pretoria',
                            'Gauteng'=>'Gauteng',
                            'Katlego'=>'Katlego',

                        )); 


        $Physical_Address = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Physical_Address');
        $Physical_Address->setLabel('Physical Address')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Physical_code = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Physical_code');
        $Physical_code->setLabel('Physical code')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Postal_Address = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Postal_Address');
        $Postal_Address->setLabel('Postal Address')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $Postal_code = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Postal_code');
        $Postal_code->setLabel('Postal code')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Telephone_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Telephone_Number');
        $Telephone_Number->setLabel('Telephone Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Fax_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Fax_Number');
        $Fax_Number->setLabel('Fax Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Cellular_Number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Cellular_Number');
        $Cellular_Number->setLabel('Cellular Number')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('Digits');

        $Organization_Email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Email');
        $Organization_Email->setLabel('Organization Email')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('EmailAddress');

        $Organization_Website = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Organization_Website');
        $Organization_Website->setLabel('Organization Website')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');




        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id, $Organization_Name, $Organization_Trading_Name, $Region, $City, $Physical_Address, $Physical_code, $Postal_Address, $Postal_code, $Telephone_Number,$Fax_Number, $Cellular_Number, $Organization_Email, $Organization_Website, $submit));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood correctly , you want to redirect after submitting your first form to another form,
you can do it easily with,

```
 $this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller');
```

where the controller will have the name of your controller and the action name would be where you will be calling the second form just like your first form.

and after submitting each form you can save or update data accordingly..

Comment: Hey i did my form should i create a new controller and action or just an ction

Comment: you can create both a new action with new controller or just new action in same controller